# Handle Lock Screen on Notification

Tags: java, android

I created lock screen app which is working fine with application launch. But I m facing a issue with notifications. Suppose I added WhatsApp in to app lock, the moment I got any WhatsApp message, lock screen appears. How can I fix it. I m monitoring foreground activity using below code. Is there some thing else to be monitored to appear lock screen.

```
private String aphpchecke() {

        String currentApp = "NULL";
        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            UsageStatsManager usm = null;
            if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP_MR1) {
                usm = (UsageStatsManager) this.getSystemService(USAGE_STATS_SERVICE);
                long time = System.currentTimeMillis();
                List<UsageStats> appList = usm.queryUsageStats(UsageStatsManager.INTERVAL_DAILY, time - 1000 * 1000, time);
                if (appList != null && appList.size() > 0) {
                    SortedMap<Long, UsageStats> mySortedMap = new TreeMap<Long, UsageStats>();
                    for (UsageStats usageStats : appList) {
                        mySortedMap.put(usageStats.getLastTimeUsed(), usageStats);
                    }
                    if (mySortedMap != null && !mySortedMap.isEmpty()) {
                        currentApp = mySortedMap.get(mySortedMap.lastKey()).getPackageName();
                    }
                }
            } else {
                ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager) this.getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
                assert am != null;
                List<ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo> tasks = am.getRunningAppProcesses();
                currentApp = tasks.get(0).processName;
            }

            Log.e("adapter", "Current App in foreground is: " + currentApp);
            return currentApp;
        } else {


            ActivityManager mActivityManager = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
            assert mActivityManager != null;
            List<ActivityManager.RunningTaskInfo> RunningTask = mActivityManager.getRunningTasks(1);
            ActivityManager.RunningTaskInfo ar = RunningTask.get(0);
            currentApp = ar.topActivity.getClassName();
            Log.i(TAG, "Top Activity " + currentApp);
            return currentApp;
        }


    }
```

As soon as WhatsApp notification came, the foreground activity shows WhatsApp package name, so logically it has to appear lock screen.

```
E/adapter: Current App in foreground is: com.google.android.apps.nexuslauncher
E/adapter: Current App in foreground is: com.whatsapp
D/FA: Logging event (FE): screen_view(_vs), Bundle[{firebase_event_origin(_o)=auto, firebase_previous_class(_pc)=LockScreen, firebase_previous_id(_pi)=7245334281643449211, firebase_screen_class(_sc)=LockScreen, firebase_screen_id(_si)=7245334281643449214}]
```

Pls guide,

Answer (score 0):

This code is not return foreground on notification.

```
public static String getForegroundPackage(UsageStatsManager usageStatsManager) {
    String packageName = null;

    final long INTERVAL = 1000 * 60;
    final long end = System.currentTimeMillis();
    final long begin = end - INTERVAL;
    final UsageEvents usageEvents = usageStatsManager.queryEvents(begin, end);
    while (usageEvents.hasNextEvent()) {
        UsageEvents.Event event = new UsageEvents.Event();
        usageEvents.getNextEvent(event);
        switch (event.getEventType()) {
            case UsageEvents.Event.MOVE_TO_FOREGROUND:
                packageName = event.getPackageName();
                break;
            case UsageEvents.Event.MOVE_TO_BACKGROUND:
                if (event.getPackageName().equals(packageName)) {
                    packageName = null;
                }
        }
    }

    return packageName;
}
```